# How to change the color of the icon on <p-calendar> and also the color of the date selected on the calendar

Tags: angular, calendar, angular8, primeng

Im using the calendar from  from primeng, its a very good component, but i feels it lacks of examples on adding custom styling on the documentation.

Im using the version with the UI-icon.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <p-calendar
              placeholder="Requeu Date"
              id="date"
              formControlName="date"
              dataType="string"
              dateFormat="MM dd, yy"
              [hideOnDateTimeSelect]="true"
              [defaultDate]="getDefaultDate()"
              [locale]="ptBR"
              [showButtonBar]="true"
              [showTime]="true"
              [disabledDays]="[0,6]"
              [showIcon]="true">              
            </p-calendar>
</div>
```

by default the icon is blue, and when you select dates its also blue by default.
i would like to change it to another color like red, and also i noticed it doesnt work properly with bootstrap containers and forms, any tips on that aspect?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the selected day you could try adding in you css this:

```
a.ui-state-active {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Instead, if you want to change the background of the icon you could try adding this:

```
.ui-button {
 background-color: red !important;
}
```